# Changes to QML files not reflected in GUI

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I took over a project running Pyqt-5 on Ubuntu 16.04.  I am very new to QML.

I have main.py which has a engine that runs qml. There are a series of qml files but for simplicity sake, let's say there is a main.qml that uses component.qml.  When component.qml is updated, nothing changes if I run main.py. However, any changes to main.qml are always reflected when running main.py.

Any suggestions as to why changes to component.qml are not reflected when I run the application? And a solution to how I may be able to have the changes in component.qml be reflected?

I have tried commenting out the entire component.qml file, no changes reflect.

Comment: provide a [MRE]. Do you use a .qrc to store the .qml?

Answer (score 0):

I have a temporary workaround by rebuilding the entire project.

I think QT, being a C++ native application, has to be recompiled if there are changes.  I think PyQT does not always trigger QT to recompile.  It is similar to the bug below.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-13334

If anyone has a better solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your answer: *I have a temporary workaround by rebuilding the entire project.* I assume you are using a .qrc and that would explain the behavior indicated in your question.

Unlike the Qt/C++ system that generates product through PyQt/Python compilation, it is an interpreted language (which is partially compiled by bytecode), so the building of the project is not the same way.

In the compilation process all the resources indicated in the .qrc are inserted in the executable in PyQt you must generate the foo_rc.py from the foo.qrc using the pyrcc tool:

```
pyrcc5 foo.qrc -o foo_rc.py
```

In conclusion:

- The project building methodology is different in Qt and PyQt, so the bug you indicate is not relevant in your case.